# How to test css styles when window is resized?

Tags: css, jestjs, react-testing-library

I am trying to test a *border* to have `display:none` when the window is resized.
I am using **jest** and **react-testing-library** for this purpose.

I have these simple css rules for my **border class**

```css
.built-with .border{
  position: absolute;
  justify-self: center;
  height: 50%;
  border-left: 1px solid black;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
@media (max-width: 590px){
  .built-with .border{
    display: none;
  }
}
```

I am trying to *assert* that when `window.innerWidth` goes less than 500, then `.border`'s `display` should be none.
Here what I am trying to do:

```js
import {render} from '@testing-library/react';
it("should have styles on different viewports", () => {
        const { container } = render(<Footer />);
        const border = container.querySelector('.border');

        const style1 = window.getComputedStyle(border);
        window = { ...window, innerWidth: 500, innerHeight: 700 };

        console.log(window.innerWidth); // 500

        const style2 = window.getComputedStyle(border);

        expect(style1.display).not.toMatch(style2.display); 
        /*expected - to not match
          during test - it matches
        */
    });
```

**Here** : `style1` has a default `window.innerWidth` of 1024 and `style2` has a `window.innerWidth`

Answer (score 0):

It seems that stylesheets are not rendered in the `jsDOM`.

Kent *(Author of Testing Library)* has discussed this issue [here](https://github.com/testing-library/react-testing-library/issues/566#issuecomment-576809980)

That's why a real *browser-like* enviroment is necessary to test CSS styles.
**Testing css styles** during **End-to-End** tests might be the best possible way.

However, there are some ways to test *css-in-js* libraries or [*styled components*](https://medium.com/@the_teacher/how-to-test-a-react-components-css-styles-with-react-testing-library-rtl-styled-components-43f744334528).